# Refatorando geração de datetime randômico (Python)

Tags: python, random

aceito sugestões pra melhorar este código

https://github.com/rg3915/django-orm/blob/master/fixtures/gen_random_values.py#L34-L45

```
import random
import datetime

def gen_timestamp(min_year=1915, max_year=1996):
    # gera um datetime no formato yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000000
    year = random.randint(min_year, max_year)
    month = random.randint(11, 12)
    day = random.randint(1, 28)
    hour = random.randint(1, 23)
    minute = random.randint(1, 59)
    second = random.randint(1, 59)
    microsecond = random.randint(1, 999999)
    date = datetime.datetime(
        year, month, day, hour, minute, second, microsecond).isoformat(" ")
    return date
```

Aceito PR.

https://github.com/rg3915/django-orm/issues/1

Comment: O mês é só novembro e dezembro, ou foi um erro de digitação? (i.e. você queria `month = random.randint(1, 12)`) E o que é "PR"?

Comment: PR é Pull Request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como eu não sei o propósito do seu código, em princípio ele me parece ok, exceto pelo fato de que nunca sorteia dias 29, 30 e 31. Se essa data (que vejo ser "ingênua", ou *naive*) representa uma data em UTC, então ele também nunca sorteia [segundos bissextos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segundo_bissexto) (*leap seconds*) - embora pela documentação Python não dá suporte a eles de qualquer forma.

Incluir esses valores faltantes traz uma complicação adicional: a probabilidade de uma data aleatória cair num mês com 31 dias é ligeiramente maior do que ela cair num mês com 30 dias (idem pra 28 e 29), bem como a dela cair num ano bissexto vs. num ano comum. De modo que, se o objetivo for uma distribuição uniforme, sortear campo por campo se tornaria excessivamente trabalhoso, longo e sujeito a erros.

Uma alternativa é sortear um delta: obtenha o valor de `min_year-01-01 00:00:00.000000` menos `(max_year+1)-01-01 00:00:00.000000` (i.e. os segundos totais de um `timedelta`, em float) e sorteie um número de segundos entre zero e esse delta, convertendo em seguida de volta pra data:

```
def gen_timestamp(min_year=1915, max_year=1996):
    min_date = datetime(min_year,  1,1)
    max_date = datetime(max_year+1,1,1)
    delta = random()*(max_date - min_date).total_seconds()
    return (min_date + timedelta(seconds=delta)).isoformat(" ")
```

Assim qualquer data no intervalo poderá ser sorteada, e o sorteio será uniforme. Veja por exemplo ele sorteando um 29 de fevereiro:

```
>>> i, d = 0, gen_timestamp()
>>> while d[5:10] != '02-29' and i < 100000:
...   i, d = i+1, gen_timestamp()
...
>>> i,d
(770, '1960-02-29 21:28:40.688135')
```

Nota: segundo [a documentação](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds), se o intervalo entre a maior e menor data for muito grande (270 anos na maioria das plataformas) esse método perde precisão nos microssegundos.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
import random
def random_datetime(start, end):
    assert isinstance(start, datetime.datetime)
    assert isinstance(end, datetime.datetime)
    start = (start - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
    end = (end - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(random.randint(start, end))
```